# php variable in another variable's value

Tags: php

So I have a variable that defines file location, but in that variable I have to combine text with another var. Here's the code I came up with:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$file = "../posts/$id.txt";
```

But that code will only find a file named `.txt`

Any help is appreciated

**Update**

The url is `example.com/edit.php?id=0`

**Update**

```
  <?php session_start();
  $id = $_GET["id"];
  $_SESSION["postId"] = $id;
  if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
  header("location: ../index.php");
  }
          function Read() {
           $id = $_SESSION["postId"];
           $file = "../posts/$id.txt";
           echo file_get_contents( $file);
           }

          function Write() {
               $id = $_SESSION["postId"];
               $file = "../posts/$id.txt";
               echo $file;
               $fp = fopen($file, "w");
               $data = $_POST["tekst"];
               fwrite($fp, $data);
               fclose($fp);

           }
    ?>

<?php
if ($_POST["submit_check"]){
Write();
};
if ($_POST["submit_check"]){
echo '<div class="info">Text updated</div>';
};
?>      

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<textarea rows="30" cols="200" name="tekst" id="alltext"><?php Read(); ?></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update text">
<input type="hidden" name="submit_check" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_GET)`. you're just assuming the 'id' parameter. if your script isn't invoked with `http://example.com?id=foo`, then it won't be...

Comment: Yes the url is passed from the previous page and the id is 0 in this case

Comment: well, if it was set, then you'd get `../posts/0.txt`. since you're not, it's not... and you need to start debugging.

Comment: `example.com/edit.php?=0` is not the same as  `example.com/edit.php?id=0`

Comment: here's what it says when you dump it: string(1) "0"

Comment: @chris85, yes i get that already

Comment: Get what? You use the link you have in the question or the one I posted?

Comment: @chris85, oh that was mistake in the post, the url was ?id=0

Comment: ...So this works now?

Comment: Try `print_r($_GET);` and `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`. What are the values?

Comment: Array ( [id] => 0 ) id=0

Comment: So `echo $_GET["id"];` returns nothing; `echo $id;` returns nothing; or `echo $file;` returns `../posts/.txt`?

Comment: all of them return the correct thing, but only .txt(and not 0.txt) file gets edited

Comment: Okay so the issue isn't with the code you've provided. Please provided the code where you are using `$file`.

Comment: please see update for the code

Comment: there must be something else going on. At face value the code above works.

Comment: @CrayonViolent yeah, i think it might be that after you click 'submit' the page loses it's parameter. Also, the content is now being read, but when sumitted writes the changes to the .txt file

Comment: that would certainly be a reason why it wouldn't work. So, in your form action='..' bit, you need to add it to the URL.  Or, put it as a hidden field in the form and look for it there (in `$_POST`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want any file name, simply:

```
$filename = $_GET["filename"];
$file = '../posts/'.$filename;
```

However, be aware of hackers doing funky stuff like

```
$_GET["filename"]="../../../../etc/passwd\x00";
```

;)

also, i suggest changing

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="?" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form action like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET) ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that form was redirecting to itself, but then it would lose it's parameter, so I changed the form action from this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

To this:

```
<form action="/users/edit.php?id=<? echo($id); ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a well-known approach in order to deal with redirects involving login and sessions.Instead of trying multiple times write/retrieve from **$_SESSION** I would just redirect to another page (login.php or index.php in this case) with a query string of the current URL (which is where you want to go back).
something like this:

```
<?php // example.com/edit.php?id=0 

if ($_SESSION["loggedin"]) {
    # REQUEST_URI: URL + query string
    header('Location: login.php?next=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

# moving $_GET here
$id = $_GET["id"];
$filename = sprintf('../posts/%s.txt');

function Read($filename) {}

function Read($filename) {}

//...
```

And another page (login.php maybe?):

```
<?php //index.php, login.php (whatever)

# do login, checks...

$redirect_back = $_GET['next']; # sanitize???

header('Location: ' . $redirect_back );
```

I think this way is pragmatic.